# iOS: Is it consider good design pattern to use your Appdelegate as a model for little things?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, model-view-controller

I used my `AppDelegate` as a model to detect if my push notification was tapped - what my push notification ID is, if one of my View Controllers is collapsed (using sidebar), if my TableViewCell was selected (this effects other view controllers). I don't use `AppDelegate` too much and usually use models.

```
 @property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger                  selectedRow;
 @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL                       isMenuCollapse;
 @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL                       notificationWasTapped;
 @property (nonatomic, assign) long long                  pushNotificationId;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it isn't.

The appDelegate, has one role - to be the application's delegate. But when you use it to store state, you are then using it as some sort of convenient singleton object.

It's a much better idea to use a separate data store for your application's state.

And don't pay any attention to Apple's application template which puts the Core Data managed object context in the app delegate file. This is bad practice that they flag up themselves in the [Core Data Snippets Document.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/stack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008283-SW1)

[image]

Comment: +1 for the important idea: The app delegate should be just a delegate for the application and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

Opinion: I'd wrap them in a distinct class so that, if the app grows, you're already prepared for true model separation.

I see no problem with the instance of the model class being available through the app delegate, analogous to how the delegate knows about the root of the view hierarchy.